# 「CGI」と「uWSGI」について

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

**PythonをWeb上で、下記何れかの方法により動作させようと思っているのですが**

```
・Nginx、CGI、Python
・Nginx、uWSGI、Python
```

---

**Q1.CGIを選択するメリットについて**
・何かありますか？
・手軽に実装できることぐらい？
・性能的にwsgiより劣るわけではない？？

---

**Q2.wsgiについて**
・Pythonに特化したインターフェース定義ですか？
・それとも、CGIに代わる新たな接続標準仕様？
・CGIが古いというわけではない？？

---

**Q3.uWSGIについて**
・wsgi規格のインターフェースを実装したもの？
・Nginxで使用できるwsgiは他にもありますか？
・uWSGIは、Nginxに特化しているわけではない？？

---

**環境**
・CentOS
・Nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1.CGIを選択するメリットについて
>   ・何かありますか？

http通信を理解する、勉強するために題材にすることはあります。
それくらい、生のhttp通信に近い仕組みです。

> ・手軽に実装できることぐらい？

手軽とは言いがたいと思います。
生のhttp通信に近いことしか実装しないのであれば手軽かもしれません。

> ・性能的にwsgiより劣るわけではない？？

生のhttp通信に近いため、セキュリティの考慮や多くのことを望まなければ、処理が少なくて済むため、高速かもしれません。

> Q2.wsgiについて
>   ・Pythonに特化したインターフェース定義ですか？

はい。

> ・それとも、CGIに代わる新たな接続標準仕様？

いいえ。
しかし、PythonのWSGIを参考にPerl用のPSGI、Ruby用のRackが開発されたそうです。

> ・CGIが古いというわけではない？？

産まれてからの経過年数はWSGIよりも古いです。

> Q3.uWSGIについて
>   ・wsgi規格のインターフェースを実装したもの？

はい。
uWSGIは比較するならGunicornなどのWebアプリケーションサーバーと比較した方がよいでしょう。
uWSGIははじめはWSGIプロトコルに対応した高機能なWebアプリケーションサーバーとして作られましたが、現在はWSGIだけでなくPSGIやRackも扱えます。

> ・Nginxで使用できるwsgiは他にもありますか？
>   ・uWSGIは、Nginxに特化しているわけではない？？

uWSGIはNginx用というわけではありません。Webアプリケーションサーバーです。
uWSGIを使っていても、NginxやApache等のWebサーバーを前段に配置するのが一般的です。
前段のWebサーバー(Nginx等)とWebアプリケーションサーバー(uWSGIやGunicorn等)はリバースプロキシ等で通信します。

Comment: 「Gunicorn」初めて知りました。回答を読んで「uWSGI」が1番無難かなと思いましたが、「CGI」「Gunicorn」も試してみようと思いました。大変参考になりました

Comment: CGIについてはかなり誤解を招く内容だと思います。CGIはHTTP通信をしているわけではありませんし、プロセス起動やプロセス間通信のコストにより確実に遅いです。

Answer (score 1):

CGIを中心に補足します。

Q1.CGIを選択するメリットについて

CGIについては、python2.7の公式ドキュメントに詳しい説明があります。python3の方にはないので内容は古いですが、説明は詳しいです。
https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/howto/webservers.html

CGIは、リクエスト毎に新しいPythonインタプリタを起動するため起動に時間がかかり非効率です。 その問題を解決したものの一つにFastCGIがあります。CGIと言った場合に、古典的CGIはもうあまり使われていないのでFastCGIのことを指す場合も多いです。古典的CGIの方は性能が劣りますが、FastCGIの方は性能的に問題はありません。PHPの場合は、php-fpmというソフトが有名でFastCGIが広く使われています。しかし、Pythonでは、公式マニュアルでWSGIの使用を勧めているためかそれほど使われていません。

NginxでFastCGIを動かしたい場合は、nginx製のFCGI Wrapというモジュールや, FastCGIの機能をもつ lighttpd Webサーバを、NginxとPythonアプリの間に置きます。

Q2.WSGIについて
WebサーバとPythonで記述されたWebアプリケーションとの標準インターフェースです。Webサーバー側でWSGIを実装したソフトウェア（いわゆるアプリケーションサーバー）には、uWSGI, Gunicorn, NGINX Unit等があります。アプリケーションサーバーを使う場合、通常はNginxをリバースプロキシにして前に置きます。リバースプロキシを使う理由は、セキュリティの向上やSSL対応、コンテンツの圧縮、画像等の静的ファイルのキャッシュをリバースプロキシで行うことによりアプリケーションサーバーの負荷軽減が図れます。

Comment: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CGI.html ← を見て気が付いたのですが、WSGI上でCGIを動作させることも出来るのですね。また、「PHP」「Python」のCGIの扱いの違いについてもずっと疑問に思っていたのですが、php-fpmはFastCGIの1種。FastCGIはPythonでも使用可能(但し、あまり使われていない)ということですね。説明分かりやすかったです