# Pythonでcgi.FieldStorage() を使わずにフォームの値を受け取る方法はありますか？

Tags: python, python3, cgi

PythonのCGIで値の受け渡し（ページ遷移）を行っています。
現在は `cgi.FieldStorage()` で値を取得しています。
ですが、Python 3.11からcgiが非推奨で、3.13からは完全に廃止されるとありました。

Python 3.11で `import cgi` すると以下のエラーが出ます。

```
DeprecationWarning: 'cgi' is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.13
```

廃止される前に別のやり方をと思い、requestsを試してみたのですが、どのように受け取ったら良いのか分からない状態です。何か良い方法はあるのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

**環境**
Windows Server 2012
Python 3.10.5
Apache 2.4.41

現在のやり方は以下です。
test.htmlでsubmitして、test.pyで値を受け取っています。

test.html

```html
<html>
<body>
<form action="./test.py" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text_name" value="ABC">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_name" value="送信">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.py

```py
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
text = form.getfirst('text_name')
print(text)
```

Comment: その非推奨/廃止の記述が有る[cgi — Common Gateway Interface support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html)の冒頭にある[cgi - PEP 594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#cgi)のリンク先で5個の機能にたいして代替方法が提示されており、FieldStorageそのものは「`FieldStorage`/`MiniFieldStorage` has no direct replacement, but can typically be replaced by using [multipart](https://pypi.org/project/multipart/) (for `POST` and `PUT` requests) or `urllib.parse.parse_qsl` (for `GET` and `HEAD` requests)」となっています。調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 申し訳ないです。そのやり方が分からなかったもので。

Comment: Apacheは必須ですか？ [サーバーサイドウェブフレームワーク](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Web_frameworks) などへの置き換えは検討不可能ですか？

Comment: pythonのwebはphpみたいに簡単に共有サーバーで遊んだりできないことが多いので、個人的にはCGIも最初の選択肢としては十分ありな気がします。情報が不足しすぎてますけどね。

Comment: 例えばこんな記事あたりが手掛かりになるでしょうか。[Handling multipart form upload with vanilla Python](https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2019/09/python-multipart/), [parse multipart/form-data, received from requests post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33369306/9014308), [Parse multipart request string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50925083/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

#### 問題があるかも知れないこと

(自己解決してるのかもだけど 注意が必要です)

> sys.stdin.read()
> で、POSTされたデータを受け取ることが出来たので、

CGI は標準入出力を行えるプログラミング言語であれば (Python含めたいてい)使えます
`cgi` モジュールは

- 各種のパース, エスケープ 逆エスケープ, エンコード・デコードなど, 用意されてるか自動的に呼び出すかしてくれるもの
- セキュリティー上の懸念を(少しは)緩和してる(かも知れない)

基本的に, CGIでは 呼び出されたスクリプトが責任をもって処理を行ない結果を返す
バッファオーバーフローなど引き起こすような要求に対処するのも, (たぶん)スクリプト側の責任の可能性がある (・・・ ので, (使わないよりも) `cgi` モジュール使うほうがよいはず)

`sys.stdin` を直接利用するのではなく, `cgi`モジュールを持ってきて `mycgi` とでも変更し利用するのが まだマシなのでは？ (確証はないけれど, 予想として)
my-cgi 的なモジュール使う場合は 現状維持であり, `sys.stdin` を利用するのは (どちらかといえば)後退になるでしょう

> 廃止される前に別のやり方をと思い、requestsを試してみたのですが

質問には現在の環境が記してあるけれど, どこまでが変更の許容範囲か不明です
requests が検討の対象になるのなら, Flask検討がまだ現状に近い気がします

---

#### CGI と WSGI の資料

他でも述べてあるように, WSGIへの移行が望ましいでしょう

参考: Python 2.7 の頃の (昔の) Python HOWTO: [Python を Web 上で使うには](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/howto/webservers.html)
前半に, CGI と, WSGI について記されている

> CGI プログラムを書くことは可能ではありますが、もはや推奨されません。 [WSGI](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/howto/webservers.html#wsgi) (詳しくは後で述べます) では CGI をエミュレートするプログラムを書くことができるので、よりよい選択肢が選べない場合には CGI としてプログラムを実行できます。

Wikipedia [Web Server Gateway Interface](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface)

前の項目で CGIはセキュリティー上懸念があることを記しましたが
WSGI の場合は WSGIサーバーが制限を行うはずで, WSGIアプリはアプリが行うことのみに専念できます

WSGI関連の質問もあり, 参考になるかも

- [https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43286/cgi-と-uwsgi-について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43286/cgi-%E3%81%A8-uwsgi-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
- [https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/83920/apache2とdjangoプロジェクトをmod-wsgiで紐付けする際のエラーについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/83920/apache2%E3%81%A8django%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%92mod-wsgi%E3%81%A7%E7%B4%90%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

#### WSGI利用のサンプルコード

① [wsgiref --- WSGI ユーティリティとリファレンス実装](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/wsgiref.html)
ページの最後辺りにサンプルコードが載っています。

② WSGI Tutorialより [Parsing the Request - Post](http://wsgi.tutorial.codepoint.net/parsing-the-request-post)

- 2006-2015 と記され, またかなり古いので 少し直したコード
  (WSGI 自体は今でも利用されてるが 動作確認程度のはずで, Django, Flask などの Webアプリフレームワークが主流と思われる)
- `cgi.FieldStorage()` の代わりの処理も含む

```py
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
from html import escape,unescape
from string import Template

html = """
<html>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="">
        <p>
           Age: <input type="text" name="age" value="${age}">
        </p>
        <p>
            Hobbies:
            <input
                name="hobbies" type="checkbox" value="software"
                ${checked_software}
            > Software
            <input
                name="hobbies" type="checkbox" value="tunning"
                ${checked_tunning}
            > Auto Tunning
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
    <p>
        Age: ${age}<br>
        Hobbies: ${hobbies}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
"""

def application(environ, start_response):

    # the environment variable CONTENT_LENGTH may be empty or missing
    try:
        request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
    except ValueError:
        request_body_size = 0

    # When the method is POST the variable will be sent
    # in the HTTP request body which is passed by the WSGI server
    # in the file like wsgi.input environment variable.
    request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
    d = parse_qs(request_body.decode())

    age = d.get('age', [''])[0] # Returns the first age value.
    hobbies = d.get('hobbies', []) # Returns a list of hobbies.

    # Always escape user input to avoid script injection
    age = unescape(age)
    hobbies = [unescape(hobby) for hobby in hobbies]

    response_body = Template(html).substitute({ # Fill the above html template in
        'checked_software': ('', 'checked')['software' in hobbies],
        'checked_tunning': ('', 'checked')['tunning' in hobbies],
        'age': age or 'Empty',
        'hobbies': ', '.join(hobbies or ['No Hobbies?'])
    }).encode()

    status = '200 OK'

    response_headers = [
        ('Content-Type', 'text/html'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))
    ]

    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [response_body]

httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

③ Flask フレームワークの例   (Flask は一例であり, このフレームワークを勧めているわけではない)

- (developer.mozilla.org) [フォームデータの送信: python_の例](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#python_%E3%81%AE%E4%BE%8B)
  Pythonスクリプトと 2つのテンプレート  https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/tree/main/html/forms/sending-form-data
- `cgi.FieldStorage()` の代わりは `request.form['say']` 辺り

```bash
$ tree .
.
├── python-example.py
└── templates
    ├── form.html
    └── greeting.html
```

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    return render_template('greeting.html', say=request.form['say'], to=request.form['to'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

上記のサンプルコード単体での実行は簡単ですが, `mod_wsgi` インストールして Apacheから呼び出すのは難しそうです
けれどバイナリダウンロード可能かも知れないので参考に

参考: (qiita.com) [FlaskアプリをApache + mod_wsgi on windowsで動かす](https://qiita.com/TakenoriHirao/items/e28624a62be2ff685123)

Comment: ありがとうございます。とりあえず現状維持が出来たので、今後はWSGIへの移行を視野に入れていきます。

Comment: DjangoもFlaskも現状CGIには対応していません。数年前くらいまではたまに見かけたbottleという小さなフレームワークではCGIがまだあるようです。apacheの衰退に伴ってか、最近はWSGI自体も流行ってないという印象を個人的には受けています(主にWSGIの先駆けとなったpython用のGunicornが頑張ってるくらいに見える)。未来は分からないものですが、現状でFrontendを(手間と工数をかけてまで)Pythonでというのは(やや古臭い印象のフレーム＋重い言語と)、長期的にいい選択なのかが個人的に疑問です(作りたいもの、流用したいもの、開発・保守メンバ、予算など次第ですが)。

Comment: 今後 cgiモジュールが廃止され使えなくなるので 代替案としての WSGIであり, (どうせ WSGI使うなら)もっと分かりやすく記述できるであろう Flaskの紹介, の回答です。/ WSGI直接使う方法は流行らないでしょう … その辺りは回答ではなく質問に対しコメントしてはどうか？ / 一応 Flask, Djangoは接戦, [FastAPIが追い上げてる感じ](https://star-history.com/#tiangolo/fastapi&pallets/flask&django/django&Date)

Answer (score 0):

Python はそれほど詳しくないので少し調べてみた程度の情報となります。

---

cgi モジュール廃止に関する文書に、関連する記述がありました。
cgi を完全に置き換えるようなモジュールは無いようです。

https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#deprecated-modules

利用したい機能に応じて、今回の例であれば multipart や urllib.parse.parse_qsl を使えばよい、といった記載があります。

https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#cgi

質問に関連する部分のみ抜粋:

> Replacements for the various parts of cgi which are not directly related to executing code are:
>
> - `FieldStorage`/`MiniFieldStorage` has no direct replacement, but can typically be replaced by using [multipart](https://pypi.org/project/multipart/) (for POST and PUT requests) or urllib.parse.parse_qsl (for GET and HEAD requests)

もしくは 既存の cgi をフォークした [legacy-cgi](https://pypi.org/project/legacy-cgi/) というモジュールもあるようです。既存 CGI スクリプトをサポート継続するのが目的のようですが、"WSGI への移行も検討するように" とも書かれています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。調べてみます。

Answer (score 0):

データの受け取りが出来ました。
https://code-notes.com/lesson/20#i1
を参考にさせていただきました。

```
import sys
sys.stdin.read()
```

で、POSTされたデータを受け取ることが出来たので、
辞書にキーと値を入れることで、
　値 = 辞書.get('キー')
と、現状の仕組みをそれほど変えることなく、ファイルデータやデータの受け取りが可能となりました。